# Concatenate class/id in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I would like to know if you can actually concatenate class's/ID's in jQuery to DRY more effectively.

**like this:**

```
$(".div1").hover(function() {
        $(".title").hide();
    });

$(".div2").hover(function() {
        $(".title").hide();
    });
```

**to this:**

```
$(".div1 + .div2").hover(function() {
        $(".title").hide();
    });
```

Is there a way of doing that?

Thank you

Comment: Using `+` will select all `.div2` elements preceded by a `.div1` element. https://api.jquery.com/next-adjacent-selector/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can select more than one element by separating each element with a comma.

```
$(".div1, .div2").hover(function() {
   $(".title").hide();
});
```

Comment: Thank you, I accepted your answer :)

Answer (score 2):

```
$(".div1, .div2").hover(function() {
```

This will fix

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I gave you one point, but I accepter the answer of the solution above yours to give help for newbies. thank you for your time :)

Answer (score 2):

```
Try This
    $(".div1, .div2").hover(function() {
            $(".title").hide();
     });
```

Comment: thank you for your help and answer, I gave you one point,but I accepted the answer below to help newbies on the website, but thank you very much for your time :)